# Reverse for 'delete_profileimage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 23}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django

I am trying to implement simple class based delete view for profile image object by defining view and url as below but I am getting error as mentioned in title.

full traceback at https://gist.github.com/webbyfox/e57e81ae4b9e6719e633676c1c19ff1a

project url.py at https://gist.github.com/webbyfox/5649570f60ae98be86206c033a5c7c75

app url.py https://gist.github.com/webbyfox/212636bacca253f4352fe446fc4eb6eb

```
class ProfileImageDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
     model = ProfileImage
     success_url = 'matrimonial/~imageupload/'
```

[image: URL.PY]

[image: FROM.PY]

Comment: Post your main urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `{% url 'namespace:delete_profileimage' pk=image.pk %}"`

where `namespace` is the string given in `include` function in project.urls.

Answer (score 2):

You should use url tag like this:

```
{% url 'users:delete_profileimage' pk=image.pk %}
```

I guess `users` is your app name

Comment: Thanks, was missing namespace